# How to add progress bar in plupload?

Tags: jquery, progress-bar, plupload

I have the following plupload code:

```
var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
                runtimes : 'html4',
                browse_button : 'pickfiles', // you can pass an id...
                container: document.getElementById('container'), // ... or DOM Element itself
                url : '<?php echo base_url();?>admin/video/post_video',
                flash_swf_url : '../js/Moxie.swf',
                silverlight_xap_url : '../js/Moxie.xap',

                filters : {
                    max_file_size : '300mb',
                    mime_types: [
                        {title : "Video files", extensions : "mp4,mov,3gp,flv,wmv"}
                    ]
                },

                init: {
                    PostInit: function() {
                        document.getElementById('filelist').innerHTML = '';

                        document.getElementById('uploadfiles').onclick = function() {
                            uploader.start();
                            return false;
                        };
                    },

                    FilesAdded: function(up, files) {
                        plupload.each(files, function(file) {
                            document.getElementById('filelist').innerHTML += '<div id="' + file.id + '">' + file.name + ' (' + plupload.formatSize(file.size) + ') <b></b></div>';
                        });
                    },

                    UploadProgress: function(up, file) {
                        document.getElementById(file.id).getElementsByTagName('b')[0].innerHTML = '<span>' + file.percent + "%</span>";
                        console.log((up.total.size-up.total.loaded)/up.total.bytesPerSec)
                    },

                    Error: function(up, err) {
                        document.getElementById('console').appendChild(document.createTextNode("\nError #" + err.code + ": " + err.message));
                    }
                }
            });
            uploader.init();
```

Now, the code works fine. However, there are some issues which I want to fix.

1. The file complete shows only 0% and 100%. No intermediate percentage
   like 25%, or 75%. i.e. the percentage gradually increasing.
2. I want to add a progress bar.
3. How to stop the page getting refreshed while plupload is working?

How can I achieve these two?

Answer (score 2):

**1)** First add html for progress bar

```
<div id="myProgress">
    <div id="myBar"></div>
</div>
```

**2)** Then add css for progress bar

```
#myProgress {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: grey;
}

#myBar {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: green;
}
```

**3)** Then in `UploadProgress` function do like this

```
  UploadProgress: function(up, file) {
      document.getElementById(file.id).getElementsByTagName('b')[0].innerHTML = '<span>' + file.percent + "%</span>";
      $('#myBar').css('width', file.percent + '%');                          
  },
```

Comment: Change `file.percent` with `up.total.percent` for total progression